# Error while try to run prisma raw query with string template

Tags: node.js, postgresql, prisma

I am having trouble executing a Prisma raw query that contains a date comparison.

I have a prisma query:

```
  const startDate = '2023-05-25 00:00:00'
  const endDate = '2023-05-25 23:59:59'
  const result = await this.databaseService.$queryRaw`
  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT sl."subscriptionId")
  FROM "subscriptionLogs" sl
  WHERE sl."createdAt" >= ${startDate} AND sl."createdAt" <= ${endDate}
  `;
```

However, when I execute the query, I get the following error:

```
prisma:query 
  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT sl."subscriptionId")
  FROM "subscriptionLogs" sl
  WHERE sl."createdAt" >= $1 AND sl."createdAt" <= $2
  
[Nest] 89231  - 06/06/2023, 13:56:15   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] 
Invalid `prisma.$queryRaw()` invocation:


  Raw query failed. Code: `22P03`. Message: `db error: ERROR: incorrect binary data format in bind parameter 1`
```

Interestingly, if I manually enter the date strings directly into the query, it works as expected:

```
WHERE sl."createdAt" >= '2023-05-25 00:00:00' AND sl."createdAt" <= '2023-05-25 23:59:59'
```

Note: I need to use a raw query, because there will be a big query next

Also i tried case like this:

```
WHERE sl."createdAt" >= '${startDate}' AND sl."createdAt" <= '${endDate}'
```